# RSpec - Type error - no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to make a test green and I'm getting this error. Even when I pry the code it shows that a string is being returned so I have no idea why the test won't green. Here is my test and error for clarification. I'm assuming this is a common error for folks.

Here is my test -

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "/api/retailers" do

describe "GET /api/retailers" do
it "Returns JSON for retailers" do

  location = Location.create!(
    city: "Portland",
    street_1: "Cherry",
    state: "Oregon",
    zip: "49490"
  )

  retailer = Retailer.create!(
    name: "Good Coffee Co.",
    description: "Hipster Good",
    image_url: "http://www.example.com/foo_bar.jpg",
    location: location
  )

  get "/api/retailers.json"

  expect(response).to be_success
  json = JSON.parse(response.body)

  expect(json["name"]).to eql("Good Coffee Co.")
  expect(json["description"]).to eql("Hipster Good")
  expect(json["image_url"]).to eql("http://www.example.com/foo_bar.jpg")
  expect(json["location"]).to eql(location.city)
end
end
end
```

here is my error message -

```
/api/retailers GET /api/retailers Returns JSON for retailers
 Failure/Error: expect(json["name"]).to eql("Good Coffee Co.")

 TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of String into Integer
 # ./spec/requests/retailers_spec.rb:28:in `[]'
 # ./spec/requests/retailers_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Something tells me you have to do `json[0]["name"]`. What is the content of the response body? You may be receiving a single element array with the content instead of the content itself.

Comment: Does your `Location` model store zip codes as string or integer?

Comment: string @DavidMeza thanks

Comment: ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
@SilverPhoenix

Comment: @CameronBass Can you write the output in your question, please? `puts response.body` should be enough. Thanks.

Comment: @CameronBass is it possible to get a sample of what `json` variable looks like? Is it an array or a hash? My guess is it would be an array, in which case you are indexing incorrectly.

Comment: 1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApiRetailers::GETApiRetailers>)> json
=> [{"id"=>31,
  "name"=>"Good Coffee Co.",
  "description"=>"Hipster Good",
  "image_url"=>"http://www.example.com/foo_bar.jpg",
  "created_at"=>"2016-04-20T18:14:17.793Z",
  "updated_at"=>"2016-04-20T18:14:17.793Z",
  "city"=>"Portland"}]

Comment: Yup, there it is. It's an array of hashes. Most likely because you are doing a get for all the retailers with `/api/retailers.json`, which is why it can only return it as an array, even if there is only one element.

Comment: It appear to be a hash @DavidMeza

Comment: No, it is an array. If you had 2 retailers it would show the second one there too. The proper way to index would be `json[0]["name"]` @CameronBass

Comment: /api/retailers GET /api/retailers Returns JSON for retailers
     Failure/Error: expect(json[0]["name"]).to eql["Good Coffee Co."]
     
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) @DavidMeza

Comment: You're using the wrong brackets in the `eql` statement in your comment code. Use parenthesis.

Comment: Right, I was about to point that out as well. `eql("Good Coffee Co.")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue was that the JSON object returns an array of objects. So the proper test expectations would be the following:

```
expect(json.first["name"]).to eq("Good Coffee Co.")
expect(json.first["description"]).to eq("Hipster Good")
expect(json.first["image_url"]).to eq("http://www.example.com/foo_bar.jpg")
expect(json.first["city"]).to eq("Portland")
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're hitting an index endpoint which is returning an array of retailers, in your case an array with a single retailer. To access this you'll need to select the first object in the array and then do your comparisons:

```
expect(json[0]['name']).to eq('Good Coffee Co.')
```

On a similar note you should be using `let` and `before` to setup your tests. Following the rspec conventions will not only make your code more readable, but easier to maintain. I've made style changes below as to how I typically lay out my tests. These are just suggestions of course and make a couple of assumptions as to the naming and scoping of your controller.

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Api::RetailersController do

  # /api/retailers
  describe '#index' do
    let!(:location) {
      Location.create!(
        city: "Portland",
        street_1: "Cherry",
        state: "Oregon",
        zip: "49490"
      )
    }

    let!(:retailer) {
      Retailer.create!(
        name: "Good Coffee Co.",
        description: "Hipster Good",
        image_url: "http://www.example.com/foo_bar.jpg",
        location: location
    )

    before(:each) do
      get :index, format: :json
      json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    end

    it 'Returns a status 200' do
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
    it 'Returns a JSON list of retailers' do
      expect(json.length).to eq(1)
    end

    # I would probably only check these in the show action
    # unless needing different data on index
    it 'Contains a name attribute' do
      expect(json[0]['name']).to eq('Good Coffee Co.')
    end
    it 'Contains a description attribute' do
      expect(json[0]['description']to eq('Hipster Good')
    end
    it 'contains an image_url attribute' do
      expect(json[0]['image_url']).to eq('http://www.example.com/foo_bar.jpg')
     end
     it 'contains a location attribute' do 
       expect(json[0]['location']).to eq(location.city)
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: I get this error now -  wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Comment: /api/retailers GET /api/retailers Returns JSON for retailers
     Failure/Error: expect(json[0]["name"]).to eql["Good Coffee Co."]

Comment: You're using square brackets in your `eql` statement. It should be `expect(json[0]["name"]).to eql("Good Coffee Co.")`. Can we see your controller code?